# Add time to mod_forensic log

Tags: apache, server

as my website is getting hacked constantly I added mod_forensic to analyze the requests and possibly identify the vulernable wordpress part.

However I do not have a timestamp in the log. As this is a very valuable piece of information, does anyone know how i can modify mod_forensics so it will work?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: We really aren't the place to modify code. Have you Googled "mod_forensics timestamp"? I'm seeing a lot of results.